# How can I make the camera appear every time I click a specific tab?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uistoryboard, xcode4.3

info: xcode 4.3.2, iOS5, using storyboard.

Created project from xcode's "Tabbed Application" template.
Did:

```
@implementation SUSecondViewController
UIImagePickerController *pic;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    pic = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pic.delegate = self;
   // [pic setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentModalViewController:pic animated:YES];
}
```

When I click the tab the first time, the camera app is displayed.
When I click the tab the second time, the default view from the template is displayed, however I want the camera to be displayed every time the tab is clicked.

How can I make the camera appear every time I click a specific tab (with f.ex. a camera icon) ?

Comment: Refer to my answer. That should help you. Also let me know in case you  need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

viewDidLoad only happens when the view is loaded.

If a view disappears / reappears it's not guaranteed that the view will get unloaded / loaded.
Maybe because there still is a strong pointer to the viewController somewhere, and the system doesn't need to free up some memory.

If you want to get it called every time the view appears, place that code in UIViewControllers

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
```

method instead of

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

You might also want to take a look here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW1

Comment: For my purposes viewWillAppear worked better than viewDidLoad. I guess it depends on your specific use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Use it on `viewDidAppear:` as on `viewDidLoad` you may not get some UI related things working as Nib is not completely loaded until `viewDidLoad` has finished executing.

So I would like you to code this on `viewDidAppear:` as shown below

```
@implementation SUSecondViewController
UIImagePickerController *pic;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    pic = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pic.delegate = self;
   // [pic setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentModalViewController:pic animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: As he did everything after [super viewDidLoad] this shouldn't be the problem here.
Also the problem doesn't occur on the first appearing of the view.

The suggestion to do it in viewWillAppear is still the correct solution tough. ;)

Comment: @Thyraz: I still don't think modal view will be presented if you call the `presentModalViewController:animated:` from `viewWillAppear:`. It has to be done from `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: Oh, sure it has to be viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear, my bad.

Comment: @Thyraz: I think changing your answer once someone else has posted the correct answer is not good. Its really not good.

Comment: @Thyraz: Actually he could have realized his mistake through my answer. It did not need you to point it out to him.